# Redhat AS 4 seg fault calling magic_buffer using Java 1.6

Tags: java, java-native-interface, segmentation-fault, redhat

I have a java class that calls a C++ class via a JNI C++ class to access the 'file' command functionality provided by libmagic.so.

- The C++ class compiles and run fine as a C++ main()

-It works fine on RHEL 5 running java 1.5 and 1.6;

-it works fine on RHEL 4 running java 1.5

-it throws a seg fault 26234 on the RHEL 4 with java 1.6

The seg fault:

1. Occurs at the call char* retptr = magic_buffer(cookie, bigbuf, 1000);
   No fault when 
   char* retptr = “a nice safe character string”;   is substituted.  This is why I conclude that the seg fault occurs at this call.
2. I use an alternative call,   char* retptr = magic_file(cookie,”/usr/include/magic.h”);    to debug buffer problems, as this call returns the same file type message requiring only the fully qualified path name of the file, rather than a buffer full of the file content.  It also throws the seg fault on the RHEL4/java 1.6 test VM.  Thus, I conclude the problem does not appear to be bad pointers or overflowing buffers in my code.
3. magic_buffer is a call to libmagic.so.  In the code previously, other successful calls to this lib are made.  This call, however, involves the lib magic database /usr/share/file/magic.
4. Compiling the C++ as an executable and running it on the problem machine works just fine.

Here's some conclusions:

A.  There is JNI involvement, because of #4

B.  Because of #1/#2, I don't believe it is a JNI implementation issue.

C.  Because of #1, #2, and #4 I don't believe it is a c++ implementation issue.

Any suggestions or comments?  (initially run on VMWare, now tested with no VM involvement)

Comment: Did that happen after an update? Can't go back to java 1.5 on RHEL4?

Comment: It might help if you posted your C++ code for JNI experts to examine.

Comment: No update was involved; this is testing new development.  We have a mixed environment of RHEL4/5 and Java 1.5/1.6.  I would like to identify the cause of the problem rather than look for a workaround with no understanding of what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to try and find a pure Java alternative.  [This page](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html) lists a number of alternatives.  Apache Tika and JMimeMagic look promising.

My second suggestion is to use `Process` to run the `file` command in a separate process and scrape the information you need from the command's standard output.  This may have (ahem) performance issues if you need to do this hundreds of times a second, but for occasional use it should be fine.

Comment: Performance is why we are seeking an alternative to spawning a new process for every instance.

Comment: I don't suggestion #1 would help.  I have posted above the line where the seg fault occurs, and why I don't think buffer issues are to blame.  Adding additional code would merely obscure the issue.  Here's some code:

char* cptr = null;
cptr = magic_file(cookie,”/usr/include/magic.h”);


that line is where the seg fault occurs.  That line is shown above.  Note that the discussion above points out that the code works with java 1.5, throws seg fault only with 1.6 under certain redhat versions.  The C++ code compiles and runs fine under all OS versions and (of course) java versions.

Comment: Alll tested.  The performance costs are significant, and not acceptable for our purposes.

Comment: See my latest comment on the question.